# Problema con Auto Incremento del ID - Usando Node JS / Express / Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, api, sequelize.js

Estoy usando - NodeJs / Express / sequelize / mysql12 - Para crear una API Rest

Lleve este problema a lo mas sencillo, nada mas tengo en
app.js
Las configuraciones minimas para poder lanzar sl servidor y este en escucha en un puerto.
mysql.js
Tengo las siguientes configuraciones:

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  database,
  user,
  password,
  {
    host,
    dialect: 'mysql'
  }
)

const dbConnect = async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log('*** Connection has been established successfully. ***');
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('*** Unable to connect to the database:  ***\n', e);
  }
}

sequelize.sync({ force: true}).then(() => {
  console.log('*** Database & tables created successfully. ***');
})

module.exports = { sequelize, dbConnect };
```

Y tengo hecho el modelo "Users" con solo 3 campos (id, username, password)
Las siguientes configuraciones

```
const User = sequelize.define(
  'user',
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: false, 
  }
);
```

El problema con el ID es el siguiente...
Cuando se realizan registros en la Tabla con todos los datos correctos, no hay problema,
Cuando se realiza un registro con el nombre de username repetido, me arroja el error, de que no esta repetido, y no se realiza el registro en la tabla.
Despues de que haya sucedido lo anterior ↑↑↑↑ el siguiente registro, entra con un ID saltado.. COmo asi

Si con el primer ejemplo el ID es 1
Con el tercer ejemplo, con el registro despues del error, se registra con 3 y no con el numero 2

Resumen del problema:
Sequelize salta un ID, cuando intenta ingresar datos equivocados, supongamos que el AI del ID esta en 5, luego ingreso un error, no pasa nada. Al siguiente registro deberia marcar 6 el ID, pero se lo salta y va a 7

Alguien me ayuda ?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

posible respuesta encontrada
[enlace aquí](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/validations-and-constraints/#unique-constraint)

basicamente la propiedad unique de username esta en true y deberia de estar en **false** para que exista mas de un unico username.